# Vim CursorLine default color

Tags: cursorline

I run Vim in terminal and it was keeping to override the background color using it's own, so I added this lines to my .vimrc

```
highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
highlight nonText ctermbg=NONE
```

and everything works fine except for the cursor line that is still using the color it was using with the overridden background which is barely visible. I've tried to add this line to .vimrc

```
highlight CursorLine ctermbg=NONE
```

but what happen is that the line disappear completely. Is there a way to make Vim to use the color from the terminal theme instead of it's own to highlight the cursor line without type the color value in .vimrc which I should change with every new theme I will use?